# Retrieve values from TransientModel in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-10

I need to return the values from TransientModel in Odoo. Storing the values by default too. Is it possible to retrieve the values from Transient Model ?

Now the value come as False.

I know transient model won't store the data.But it was stored as default. Also in some of the settings in Odoo it is retrieving too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `set_values` and `get_values` methods to store and retrieve the values respectively.

Here is the example,

```py
test_field = fields.Boolean('Field')

@api.multi
def set_values(self):
    ICPSudo = self.env['ir.config_parameter'].sudo()
    super(ResConfigSettings, self).set_values()
    ICPSudo.set_param("key_test_field", value)


@api.model
def get_values(self):
    ICPSudo = self.env['ir.config_parameter'].sudo()
    res = super(ResConfigSettings, self).get_values()
    res.update(
        test_field=ICPSudo.get_param('key_test_field'),
```